# How can I calculate the optimal solution?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, assembly

I have some imaginary hardware.  It only has exactly 2 memory addresses and 2 registers.  It has only two instructions available - subtract a memory address from a register, and move a register's value into memory.  It needs to perform the operation of moving the value from one memory address to the other.  Each of the four values in memory and registers have unknown values.  All of that looks like this:

Storage:

```
Memory #1 (m1) -> a
Memory #2 (m2) -> b
Register #1 (r1) -> c
Register #2 (r2) -> d
```

Instructions:

```
mov m r //Copies value at r into m
sub r m //Subtracts the value in m from r
```

Possible Combinations:

```
mov m1 r1
mov m1 r2
mov m2 r1
mov m2 r2
sub r1 m1
sub r1 m2
sub r2 m1
sub r2 m2
```

Objective:

```
Set the value in m2 to equal a (which is the value initially stored in m1).
```

Possible Solution  (Spoiler Alert!):

```
//Comments show respective value for m1, m2, r1, r2
//a b c d
mov m2 r1  //a c c d
sub r1 m2  //a c 0 d
mov m2 r1  //a 0 0 d
sub r1 m1  //a 0 -a d
mov m1 r1  //-a 0 -a d
sub r1 m1  //-a 0 0 d
sub r1 m1  //-a 0 a d
mov m2 r1  //-a a a d
```

This solution took 8 moves.  I was trying to find a better solution by writing a program to brute force all of the solutions (up to 10 moves).  I wrote it in Java.  This is what I came up with:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class AssemblyChallenge {

    //This is the main logic.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Memory memory1 = new Memory();
        Memory memory2 = new Memory();
        while (memory1.value == memory2.value) {
            memory2 = new Memory();
        }
        Register register1 = new Register();
        Register register2 = new Register();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
                        for (int m = 0; m < 8; m++) {
                            for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
                                for (int o = 0; o < 8; o++) {
                                    for (int p = 0; p < 8; p++) {
                                        for (int q = 0; q < 8; q++) {
                                            for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) {
                                                ArrayList<Integer> instructions = new ArrayList<>();
                                                instructions.add(i);
                                                instructions.add(j);
                                                instructions.add(k);
                                                instructions.add(l);
                                                instructions.add(m);
                                                instructions.add(n);
                                                instructions.add(o);
                                                instructions.add(p);
                                                instructions.add(q);
                                                instructions.add(r);
                                                runInstructions(instructions, memory1, memory2, register1, register2);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //This runs an set of instruction sets
    public static void runInstructions(ArrayList<Integer> instructions, Memory memory1, Memory memory2, Register register1, Register register2) {
        int memoryValue1 = memory1.value;
        for (int instruction : instructions) {
            switch (instruction) {
                case 0:
                    moveRegisterIntoMemory(memory1, register1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    moveRegisterIntoMemory(memory1, register2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    moveRegisterIntoMemory(memory2, register1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    moveRegisterIntoMemory(memory2, register2);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    subtractMemoryFromRegister(register1, memory1);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    subtractMemoryFromRegister(register1, memory2);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    subtractMemoryFromRegister(register2, memory1);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    subtractMemoryFromRegister(register2, memory2);
                    break;
            }
            if (memoryValue1 == memory2.value) {
//                System.out.println(instructions + " succeeded in 10 moves or less!");
            }
            System.out.println(instructions.size());
        }
    }

    //This takes the value in the register and copies it into the value at the memory
    public static void moveRegisterIntoMemory(Memory memory, Register register) {
        memory.value = register.value;
    }

    //This takes the value in the memory and subtracts it from the value in the register
    public static void subtractMemoryFromRegister(Register register, Memory memory) {
        register.value -= memory.value;
    }

    //This is the Memory class which stores a random value
    static class Memory {
        public int value;

        public Memory() {
            Random random = new Random();
            value = random.nextInt(20000) - 10000;
        }
    }

    //This is the Register class which stores a random value
    static class Register {
        public int value;

        public Register() {
            Random random = new Random();
            value = random.nextInt(20000) - 10000;
        }
    }
}
```

This issue is that it runs way too slow, and it does not seem like it will calculate 1,073,741,824 possibilities in realistic time.  How can I fix my program so that I can find an optimal solution to this problem?  Is there away around a brute force approach?

Comment: Why do you need to solve this?

Comment: @KristofferE For fun.  To learn.

Comment: One way to optimize this code at least a little bit is, don't store all the instriction sets. Instead of generating a set of instructions, and then adding it to the arraylist, evaluate it immediately, print the solution and move on to the next combination. This way you at least won't eat up the entire memory - if my math is correct, the whole instructionSets takes at least 40GB  in raw data. (1073741824 combinations * 10 numbers *4 bytes per int).

Comment: @CptBartender Good call. Updated code in question

Comment: You already have an 8 instruction solution, why search for anything longer than 7 then? And you in fact don't need any array/list, 10*3 bits fit in an int, and using that you can also use just a single loop. Makes the "run code" step only insignificantly more complicated.

Comment: Good point about the ArrayList. I am changing that now.  But how would i do this in a single loop?

Comment: Well once you pack the whole list of instructions into a single int, you're really search searching through a range of ints (0 through 07777777777 in octal)

Comment: The third instruction in your example, `mov m2,r1` (which just stores 0 in m2), is unnecessary.

Comment: @harold i never pack them into a single int. i pack them into an array

Comment: @JimMischel which is exactly why i wanted this program to work :) nice catch

Comment: @Evorlor I know you don't. But that was part of my suggestion. You can do it with a single loop and an array too of course, just unpack the loop variable into the array..

Comment: @harold I am not quite following :-/

Comment: Each instruction is 3 bits. So for one instruction, it's 0 - 7, for two instructions, 0 - 63, for three instructions the search space is 0 - 511 and so on. That's what you're doing now too, effectively, but with a loop for every octal digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CptBartender and harold, I have a solution!  It prints out all of the solutions with fewer than 8 instructions in about 1 second.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class AssemblyChallenge {
    //Possible solutions to be confirmed.
    private static ArrayList<int[]> solutions = new ArrayList<>();

    //This is the main logic.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Memory memory1 = new Memory();
        Memory memory2 = new Memory();
        while (memory1.value == memory2.value) {
            memory2 = new Memory();
        }
        Register register1 = new Register();
        Register register2 = new Register();
        int startingMemoryValue1 = memory1.value;
        int startingMemoryValue2 = memory2.value;
        int startingRegisterValue1 = register1.value;
        int startingRegisterValue2 = register2.value;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
                        for (int m = 0; m < 8; m++) {
                            for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
                                for (int o = 0; o < 8; o++) {
                                    for (int p = 0; p < 8; p++) {
                                        memory1.value = startingMemoryValue1;
                                        memory2.value = startingMemoryValue2;
                                        register1.value = startingRegisterValue1;
                                        register2.value = startingRegisterValue2;
                                        int[] instructions = new int[8];
                                        instructions[0] = i;
                                        instructions[1] = j;
                                        instructions[2] = k;
                                        instructions[3] = l;
                                        instructions[4] = m;
                                        instructions[5] = n;
                                        instructions[6] = o;
                                        instructions[7] = p;
                                        runInstructions(instructions, memory1, memory2, register1, register2);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        confirmSolutions();
    }

    //This runs an set of instruction sets
    public static boolean runInstructions(int[] instructions, Memory memory1, Memory memory2, Register register1, Register register2) {
        int memoryValue1 = memory1.value;
        int numMoves = 0;
        for (int instruction : instructions) {
            numMoves++;
            switch (instruction) {
                case 0:
                    moveRegisterIntoMemory(memory1, register1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    moveRegisterIntoMemory(memory1, register2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    moveRegisterIntoMemory(memory2, register1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    moveRegisterIntoMemory(memory2, register2);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    subtractMemoryFromRegister(register1, memory1);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    subtractMemoryFromRegister(register1, memory2);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    subtractMemoryFromRegister(register2, memory1);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    subtractMemoryFromRegister(register2, memory2);
                    break;
            }
            if (memoryValue1 == memory2.value) {
                int[] solution = Arrays.copyOfRange(instructions, 0, numMoves);
                if (!isSolutionAlreadyFound(solution)) {
                    solutions.add(solution);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isSolutionAlreadyFound(int[] solution) {
        for (int[] foundSolution : solutions) {
            if (Arrays.equals(solution, foundSolution)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void confirmSolutions() {
        Memory memory1 = new Memory();
        Memory memory2 = new Memory();
        while (memory1.value == memory2.value) {
            memory2 = new Memory();
        }
        Register register1 = new Register();
        Register register2 = new Register();
        int startingMemoryValue1 = memory1.value;
        int startingMemoryValue2 = memory2.value;
        int startingRegisterValue1 = register1.value;
        int startingRegisterValue2 = register2.value;
        for (int i = 0; i < solutions.size(); i++) {
            memory1.value = startingMemoryValue1;
            memory2.value = startingMemoryValue2;
            register1.value = startingRegisterValue1;
            register2.value = startingRegisterValue2;
            boolean success = runInstructions(solutions.get(i), memory1, memory2, register1, register2);
            if (success && solutions.get(i).length < 8) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(solutions.get(i)) + " was successful in " + solutions.get(i).length + " moves!");
            }
        }
    }

    //This takes the value in the register and copies it into the value at the memory
    public static void moveRegisterIntoMemory(Memory memory, Register register) {
        memory.value = register.value;
    }

    //This takes the value in the memory and subtracts it from the value in the register
    public static void subtractMemoryFromRegister(Register register, Memory memory) {
        register.value -= memory.value;
    }

    //This is the Memory class which stores a random value
    static class Memory {
        public int value;

        public Memory() {
            Random random = new Random();
            value = random.nextInt(20000) - 10000;
        }
    }

    //This is the Register class which stores a random value
    static class Register {
        public int value;

        public Register() {
            Random random = new Random();
            value = random.nextInt(20000) - 10000;
        }
    }
}
```

I searched for only the solutions with less than 8 moves, and the output was:

```
[2, 4, 5, 0, 4, 4, 2] was successful in 7 moves!
[2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2] was successful in 7 moves!
[2, 5, 4, 0, 4, 4, 2] was successful in 7 moves!
[2, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 2] was successful in 7 moves!
[3, 6, 7, 1, 6, 6, 3] was successful in 7 moves!
[3, 6, 7, 3, 7, 7, 3] was successful in 7 moves!
[3, 7, 6, 1, 6, 6, 3] was successful in 7 moves!
[3, 7, 6, 3, 7, 7, 3] was successful in 7 moves!
```

One hiccup I had to overcome was correct solutions by random chance.  My solution was just to run the check again with different numbers.  This of course, does have a small chance of having a double false positive.

**The fewest instructions possible is 7.**

Answer (score 0):

To move m1 to m2, this 7 instruction sequence only using r1 seems fairly straightforward:

```
             m1 m2 r1 r2
              a  b  c  d
mov r1 m2        c   
sub m2 r1           0
sub m1 r1          -a
mov r1 m2       -a
sub m2 r1           0
sub m2 r1           a
mov r1 m2        a
```

Since there are no register to register instructions, it's a bit misleading to include r2, since it's not needed.